# Issue with the Resource File Conversion

Tags: c#, resources

Here is the requirement:

Migrate the project resource file from one version to another version using Resourcefile converter utility.(ConvertResx)

I have created a simple windows application project. Set the localization property in the design time. In the .resx file localizable property entry has been set with 'MetaData' attribute. During the resource file conversion it convert all the entries in .resx file,but the localizable property attribute set with 'Data' attribute instead of 'Metadata' attribute.

UseResxDataNodes' class placed both the data and metadata attribute entries in the same collection.

ResXResourceReader reader = new ResXResourceReader(path0);

```
        reader.UseResXDataNodes = true;
```

In order to retrieve the metadata collection entries, i have used the below code

iDictionaryEnumerator7 = reader.GetMetadataEnumerator();

But unable to read the metadata properties (localizable) with 'Metadata' attribute tag. it has been set with 'Data' tag in the resx file after resource file conversion.

Could you please help me on this issue, how to read the metadata attributes (design-time property attributes from the .resx file and migrate the referred assemblies to the latest version and   write it into the .resx file ) how to migrate the metadata attribute entries in the .resx files.

Regards,
Sivaguru s

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same problem trying to write out a resource file to the same format as the original. After some searching and trial/error, I came up with the following solution to properly write out the metadata nodes.

```
ResXResourceReader readerData = new ResXResourceReader(new StringReader(sw.ToString()));
ResXResourceReader readerMetaData = new ResXResourceReader(new StringReader(sw.ToString()));

//Flag to read nodes as ResXDataNode, instead of key/value pairs, to preserve Comments.
readerData.UseResXDataNodes = true;

ResXResourceWriter writer = new ResXResourceWriter(this.FilePath);

foreach (DictionaryEntry resEntry in readerData)
{
    ResXDataNode node = resEntry.Value as ResXDataNode;

    if (node != null)
    {
        DictionaryEntry metaDataEntry;

        //Check if node is metadata. The reader does not distinguish between 
        //data and metadata when UseResXDataNodes flags is set to true.
        //http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/524508/resxresourcereader-does-not-split-data-and-metadata-entries-when-useresxdatanodes-is-true
        if (IsMetaData(readerMetaData, resEntry, out metaDataEntry))
        {
            writer.AddMetadata(metaDataEntry.Key.ToString(), metaDataEntry.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            writer.AddResource(node);
        }
    }   
}

writer.Generate(); //write to the file
writer.Close();

readerData.Close();
readerMetaData.Close();
```

---

```
/// <summary>
/// Check if resource data is metadata. If so, return the metadata node.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="metaDataReader"></param>
/// <param name="resEntry"></param>
/// <param name="metaData"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private static bool IsMetaData(ResXResourceReader metaDataReader, DictionaryEntry resEntry, out DictionaryEntry metaData)
{
    IDictionaryEnumerator metadataEnumerator = metaDataReader.GetMetadataEnumerator();

    while (metadataEnumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        if (metadataEnumerator.Entry.Key.Equals(resEntry.Key))
        {
            metaData = metadataEnumerator.Entry;
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```